# asynchronous data load iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have a list of loaded image in my application with LazyLoader, I want to update this list when I add an image in the database. I use NSURLConnection to load images

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? On which part do you need help? Below is a tentative answer to your question, the way I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest option would be to put your code in a block and let it be executed asynchronously. That way you keep a simple flow.

**To that end, use:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
^{

    // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
    // Whatever you put in here will be executes asynchronously.
});
```

**Edit in response to OP's comments:**

NSURLConnection's method:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate
```

can't be used. According to the documentation:

> The delegate object for the connection. The delegate will receive
>   delegate messages as the load progresses. Messages to the delegate
>   will be sent on the thread that calls this method. By default, for the
>   connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run loop must be
>   operating in the default run loop mode. See scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:
>   to change the run loop and mode.

**The solution is to use:**

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

> No special threading or run loop configuration is necessary in the
>   calling thread in order to perform a synchronous load.

**Or to use:**

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

with a block completion handler.

**Notes:**

If the task to perform are only to be done after the request is done (e.g. calling a delegate), then `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is the best option.

Comment: NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.2/piwigo/ws.php?format=json&method=pwg.categories.getImages"];
                       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                                          timeoutInterval:5.0];
                 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                       imagesConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]  initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: i Put this code into your bloc and it does not working

Comment: @MohamedYahyaMzoughi It can't be working like this. See the documentation. You need to use `sendSynchronousRequest` and update your code accordingly (you will call the delegate yourself after the call to `sendSynchronousRequest` returns.